# Using Ubuntu 10.04 as access point

Tags: networking, ubuntu, routing, wifi, access-point

Is there an easy way to configure Ubuntu laptop as access point?
Sometimes when I only have cable connection to the internet I would like to give my gadgets access to the internet using WiFi. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, and there are various ways to do so. One way would be to use an ad-hoc connection, and the other way to setup a real access point.

http://www.raphink.info/2009/01/setting-up-access-point-with-wpa-on.html covers how to setup the latter. The instructions were written for Ubuntu Intrepid, so I cannot guarantee that they still work ; there might be some adjustments to make.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your wifi card. Not all cards are capable of acting as an AP. I have had most luck with the MadWiFi drivers on ubuntu, but it was a year since I last tried. From my experience there is no pretty GUI that works, and the CLI configuration is painful.